# Can mongo aggregate $push data from another query?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

It's hard to describe, I'm using mongodb and aggregate method to get a list data group by 2 fields. But some records have only 1 in that 2 fields and I want also to include the records to list.

Example:

```
// Aggregate query:

db.collectionA.aggregate([{
  $group: {
    _id: {
      field1: '$field1',
      field2: '$field2'
    },
    $push: {
      value: '$value'
    }
  }
}]);

// Above query result look like
results = [{
  _id: { field1: '1', field2: '2', value: [1, 2, 3] },
}]


// I have to push all record have only one field1 = 1 or field2 = 2 to value
results.forEach((result) => {
  const moreData = db.collectionA.find({
    $or: [{ field1: result._id.field1 }, { field2: result._id.field2 }]
  });

  result.value.push(moreData);
})
```

My expect is can we handle the last section in same the query aggregate. Can mongo $push by a value of a query result

```
db.collectionA.aggregate([{
  $group: {
    _id: {
      field1: '$field1',
      field2: '$field2'
    },
    value: {
      db.collectionA.find({ $or: [{ field1: '$_id.field1', field2: '$_id.field2' }]})
    }
  }
}])
```

Comment: could you provide sample data

Comment: You can use $lookup to find those documents